# javascript access array properties passed into a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

through a callback function, how can I access properties each value of an array of strings? I'd like to be able to use Array#filter to keep the strings whose length is less than x.

```
var arr1 = [
  'Tempor quis esse consequat sunt ea eiusmod.',
  'Id culpa ad proident ad nulla laborum incididunt.',
  'Ullamco in ea et ad anim ulam est.',
  'Est ut irure irure nisi.'
];
```

here is my filter function:

```
var arr2 = arr1.filter(function(value, index, array) {
    return value.length < x;
});
```

alas, I get a TypeError message which reads "`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`"

All I'm trying to do is have my callback return the strings which have a length of less than x characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your program is correct, and so is your filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, obviusly x is not defined, but i assume you define x in outer context so inside filter callback it's available trought the closure.

Where you are running this code?

In last firefox console it's working good.